# EF6 DBContext (Multiple db), UnitofWork, Repository, Autofac IOC dependencies

Tags: entity-framework-6, autofac

I am using Ef6 in a .net web Api application. 
This is a legacy monolith which we are trying to convert to a micro service CQRS architecture. Currently we are facing concurrency issues using EF6 and I don't have a clue how to go about sorting this out.
To start with I have two databases(write and read). We are using sql server 2012 as RDBMS. I am using IOC/DI with Autofac and since we have 2 db's i wanted to create 2 different context objects and this is how the code looks like.

//Unit of Work constructor

```
   public UnitOfWork(IContext readContext, IContext writeContext, IMapper 
    mapper)
    {
       _readContext = readContext;
      _writeContext = writeContext;
      _mapper = mapper; //this is for the automapper
    }
```

This creates 2 contexts objects from IContext interface.

//IContext interface has 2 custom context objects as follows

```
public partial class MyWriteContext : IContext,IDisposable
{
}

public partial class MyReadContext : IContext,IDisposable
{
}
```

We have created these 2 classes as partial on purpose since these are the same names we are using to create the actual Ef6 dbcontexts

//Actual Entity Framework context objects generated by reverse poco

```
public partial class EfWriteContext : DbContext{}

partial class EFReadContext : DbContext{}
```

This my Autofac configuration for the same dbcontext, unit of work and Generic repository all defined in autofac modules and registered and resolved in the Web API Startup.cs

//Context Autofac Registration module

```
protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<MyReadContext>()
                .Named<IContext>("MyReadContext")
                .InstancePerDependency();

            builder.RegisterType<MyWriteContext>()
                   .Named<IContext>("MyWriteContext")
                   .InstancePerDependency();
        }

        protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
        {
            registration.Preparing -= Registration_Preparing;
            registration.Preparing += Registration_Preparing;
        }

        private void Registration_Preparing(object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
        {
            Parameter parameter = new ResolvedParameter(
                (pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IContext),
                                        (pi, c) =>
                                        {
                                            if (pi.Name.Equals("readContext", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                            {
                                                return c.ResolveNamed<IContext>("MyReadContext");
                                            }
                                            else if (pi.Name.Equals("writeContext", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                            {
                                                return c.ResolveNamed<IContext>("MyWriteContext");
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                return c.ResolveNamed<IContext>("MyReadContext");
                                            }
                                        });
            e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Concat(new Parameter[] { parameter });
        }
```

//Unit of work

```
 builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerDependency();
```

//Repository

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(Assembly.Load("Infrastructure"))
                          .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Repository"))
                          .AsImplementedInterfaces()
                          .InstancePerDependency();
```

//The Repository constructor

```
public Repository(IContext dbContext)
 {
    context = dbContext;
    _dbset = context.Set<TEntity>();
 }
```

This code works perfectly and inserts & updates the data in case of a single user when writecontext.SaveChanges() is called. It even works if multiple users have a time lag between them when saving the data in the DB, but the problem occurs when 2 users are actually trying to save the data in DB at the same time. It then starts throwing errors

1. The argument 'entitySetName' cannot be null, empty or contain only white space.
2. Item is already exists in the model.
3. Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key in object . The duplicate key value is (0, 4862). The statement has been terminated.

and then the subsequent calls also start failing for all the users.